# Choosing biggest possible font size in table cell using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating tombola board.
Code is as follows:

```js
var tambola_board = {
  cell_size: 0,
  numbers_gone: [],
  numbers_gone_count: 0,
  numbers_left: 90
};

let x_width = window.screen.availHeight;
let y_height = window.screen.availWidth;
console.log("width is", x_width);
console.log("height is", y_height);

var small_dimension;
if (x_width > y_height)
  small_dimension = y_height;
else
  small_dimension = x_width;

tambola_board.cell_size = ~~(small_dimension / 12);
console.log("cell size of tambola board will be", tambola_board.cell_size);

cell_style = "height:" + tambola_board.cell_size + "px;width:" + tambola_board.cell_size + "px;border: 1px solid black;text-align:center";
console.log("cell style will be", cell_style);

var table = document.getElementById("tambola_board");
for (let row_num = 0; row_num < 9; row_num++) {
  row_value = 81 - 10 * row_num;
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  for (let cell_num = 0; cell_num < 10; cell_num++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(cell_num);
    cell.style = cell_style;
    cell_value = row_value + cell_num;
    cell.innerHTML = cell_value.toString();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<table id="tambola_board" style="border: 1px solid black">
</table>
```

I will add JavaScript to change background color and text color in table cell as numbers are called but that is not of concern for this question.

Here my aim is to use biggest possible number in table cell and I want to use method that is available by default in common browsers and does not depend on internet.
Can you suggest as per this requirement?

My thinking is that, if there is a way to calculate size of text in pixel then I will successively increase font size till text just fits in the table cell or if I get exact pixel width and height occupied by current text then I will get a factor for font size in that table cell for quick fitting. I have tried using `offsetWidth` and `getComputedStyle`, but that gave same value for all cells.

Comment: i had tried getComputedStyle , offsetWidth and getBoundingClientRect on table cell but it gave constant value for all cells  . See gre_gor solution below for right approach .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of table cells is dependent on other cells in their row/column, so getting their dimensions based on font size alone is not possible.

You need to wrap the number in a `span` element and get the dimension of that.

```js
function fit_text(el, max_width, max_height) {
  const el_box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const { width, height } = el_box;
  const hs = max_width / width;
  const vs = max_height / height;
  el.style.fontSize = Math.min(hs, vs) + "em";
}

var tambola_board = {
  cell_size: 0,
  numbers_gone: [],
  numbers_gone_count: 0,
  numbers_left: 90
};

let x_width = window.screen.availHeight;
let y_height = window.screen.availWidth;
console.log("width is", x_width);
console.log("height is", y_height);

var small_dimension = Math.min(x_width, y_height);

tambola_board.cell_size = Math.floor(small_dimension / 12);
console.log("cell size of tambola board will be", tambola_board.cell_size);

var table = document.getElementById("tambola_board");
table.style.setProperty("--cell-size", tambola_board.cell_size + "px");
for (let row_num = 0; row_num < 9; row_num++) {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  for (let col_num = 1; col_num <= 10; col_num++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    // create span element containing the number
    let cell_span = document.createElement("span");
    cell_span.textContent = row_num * 10 + col_num;
    // add add it to the cell
    cell.appendChild(cell_span);
    // call after the span was added to the DOM, otherwise it's impossible to calculate the dimensions
    fit_text(cell_span, tambola_board.cell_size, tambola_board.cell_size);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#tambola_board {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#tambola_board td {
  width: var(--cell-size);
  height: var(--cell-size);
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<table id="tambola_board">
</table>
```

I also improved you code slightly, by using CSS variables and simplified table generation.

Comment: thanks . i know very basic javascript . you seem to be an expert , i will learn from your solution . thanks .